# Unique SHA-1 digest generation

Tags: python, sha

In Python I'm creating 3 objects each of whom has a unique identifier.

The way I generate this unique identifier in all these objects is the following:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        unique_id = hashlib.sha1(str(time.time())).hexdigest()
```

I create these objects one after the other like this:

```
a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()
```

All these instances end up having the same `unique_id` because not enough time lapses between their creation.

I've resorted to putting a `sleep(0.1)` between object creations but I'm sure there's more elegant ways to solve this problem.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why not draw out 128 bytes of the system's entropy and use that instead?

Comment: Can you use a [UUID](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) instead?

Comment: Ignacio, can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: Nice one millimoose uuid.uuid4() could do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python objects already have a unique identifier, which is their `id`. This is only unique as long as the objects stay in existence, though; the `id` may be reused after an object is deleted.

You can also use the [`uuid`](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) module from the standard library, or just keep a counter in the class:

```
class Foo(object):
    __COUNT = 0
    # or: __COUNT = random.randint(0, 2**N - 1)

    def __init__(self):
        self.unique_id = self.__COUNT  # or take the SHA1 of the count
        type(self).__COUNT += 1
```

Comment: The idea of the id() builtin is good, I like it better than my hexdigest as I'm passing this info to an ajax call and I'd rather have shorter urls (although none is seeing them)

Comment: @L.DeLeo: then you could also generate a UUID and truncate it. Watch out with `id`; it's commonly implemented as a memory address and might give away details of your server to the outside world. That's a potential security hazard.

Comment: But then I'd have collision problems (although maybe not very likely). If I'll have to scale my app beyond 1 Python interpreter maybe also the id() solution might become a problem but in that case I'll resort to something else.

Comment: @L.DeLeo: If you want them to be unique even across different machines, then better pick UUID, as I and lasrmans proposed. UUID guarantee uniqueness, but small integer IDs are guaranteed to be non-unique after trying small amount of possibilities (eg. for 4-digit IDs are depleted after at most 9999 uses). For generating unique identifiers in a single script run solution with tracking last used incremental ID is enough.

Comment: @L.DeLeo: On many platforms, when you create an object, it often has the same id as the most recently destroyed object. So id is a great way to encourage as many collisions as possible, which is the exact opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two ways to create unique identifiers:

1. Use incremental value, usually integer, to generate unique key
2. Use eg. UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)

### Incremental identifiers

The first choice is obvious: whether you do it on the database layer or on the application layer, you need to store information on which identifier was generated last, so you can generate another by incrementing it.

Example solution is here:

```
>>> class Incremental(object):
    _last_id = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Incremental._last_id += 1
        self.id = Incremental._last_id


>>> class MyClass(Incremental):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyClass with id=%s' % self.id


>>> a = MyClass()
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> a, b, c
(MyClass with id=1, MyClass with id=2, MyClass with id=3)
```

Although take a look at what others proposed - their proposals may be better suited when it comes to incremental IDs.

### Universally Unique Identifiers

The second choice is just using proper tool for proper task: UUID is specifically designed to give you unique identifier.

There is a module called [UUID](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) bundled with standard Python installation that you can use for this:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> str(uuid.uuid1())
'0baa65ea-b665-11e1-b721-b80305056d6a'
```

### Translating them into hashes

You can translate both values to SHA-1 hashes, if you wish:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1(str(1)).hexdigest()
'356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'
>>> hashlib.sha1('0baa65ea-b665-11e1-b721-b80305056d6a').hexdigest()
'46bd64c5f4a81b90539d7302d030e01378ef6d6e'
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. How much safer are UUID compared to id() in the context of a single Python interpreter?

Comment: @L.DeLeo: You can hash both of them, but UUIDs are a lot safer, as they do not disclose much about your system (depending on which UUID version you use, sometimes you can determine that two UUIDs were generated by the same host). For generating safe unique identifiers UUIDs are the way. In addition you can always hash them and get SHA-1 digest. Integer identifiers are not so unique, however - if `id()` gives you integer between eg. `1` and `10000000` (10kk), then there are 10 milion possibilities, even if you hash it. With UUID you theoretically have 16**32 possibilities.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that UUID was specifically designed exactly for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding 1 to the first, and 2 to the second?

I don't know python well enough to fix it, but the idea would be to write

```
a = Foo(0)
b = Foo(1)
c = Foo(2)
```

and have the class compute

```
unique_id = hashlib.sha1(str(time.time()+offset)).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Yes, I could even do this but in my case it would require keeping a count as I'm not sure beforehand how many objects I'm going to create. (The example is a little simplified).